# MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection on bulkwrite inserts

Tags: mongodb

I am getting a duplicate key error on the basic `_id` field when trying to bulkwrite some test documents. I basically have 9 inserts that I want to insert over and over. I don't see why this is a problem, because i have not given them an `_id` manually. Somehow while doing this there is a duplicate key, even though these keys should be assigned automatically.

```
const inserts= [
  { 
    insertOne: {
     document: {
       name: "a"
     }
    }
  },

  { 
    insertOne: {
     document: {
       name: "b"
     }
    }
  },
  // and on a few more times
]
```

Then I want to write a lot of docs at once so I just add those same inserts over and over

```
const ops: Promise<any>[] = [];
const bulkInserts: any[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
    bulkInserts.push(...inserts);
  }
  ops.push(collection.bulkWrite(bulkInserts));
}

await Promise.all(ops);
```

But after one round of inserts, I get the duplicate key error on index `_id_`. I am not manually setting the id so how can this happen?

Comment: probably because it has the same references throughout the bulkInserts array when you are doing the ... , not sure if that

Comment: maybe try with `bulkInserts.push(...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inserts)));` if same thing happens

Comment: Thanks that was it (also had to move bulkInserts into the first loop). It seems that at some point mongo adds an _id during the bulkWrite operation to the argument object(s).

Comment: cool you can give an answer with what worked

Comment: @radop33392 That is correct, mongodb drivers add the _id field before sending the operation to the server.  Since Javascript `.push` will push a reference to the object, changing one changes them all. @cmgchess' workaround creates a brand new object for each push so they aren't just references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that mongodb driver will add an _id to each object being inserted, so it is necessary to not directly reuse/reference the original documents being inserted.

Working code

```
const ops: Promise<any>[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  const bulkInserts: any[] = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
    // Or manually delete all _ids 
    bulkInserts.push(...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inserts)));
  }
  ops.push(collection.bulkWrite(bulkInserts));
}

await Promise.all(ops);
```

Comment: A late thought on this, instead of converting the array of objects to string and back, you could use `bulkInserts.push(...inserts.map(o=>Object.assign({},o)))`